# KMeans cluster with multiple columns using grouped dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, k-means

I am currently working on k-means clustering of multiple groups using groupby.

The data I'm working on looks like this

| date | permno | mom1m | mom2m | ... | mom48m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2004-01-31 | 80000 | 0.515 | -0.32 | ... | 0.773 |
| 2004-02-29 | 80000 | 0.415 | -0.043 | ... | 0.64 |
| 2004-03-31 | 80000 | 0.314 | 0.045 | ... | 0.43 |
| 2004-01-30 | 80001 | 0.643 | -0.234 | ... | 0.34 |
| 2004-02-29 | 80001 | 0.646 | -0.456 | ... | 0.646 |
| 2004-03-31 | 80001 | 0.876 | -0.044 | ... | 0.321 |
| 2004-01-31 | 80002 | 0.453 | 0.045 | ... | 0.324 |

I will be grouping the dataframe based on the dates and I want to perform k-means clustering starting from the columns `mom2m` to `mom48m`.

I would want to have a separate column that shows the labels as well.

What I have done until now is to make a function that performs the k-means clustering and use `transform`.

```
def cluster(X, n_clusters):
    features = X[features_to_KMeans]
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    y = kmeans.fit_predict(features)
    return y

crsp['cluster_id'] = crsp.groupby("date").transform(cluster, n_clusters=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

For 'scikit-learn', the data needs to be converted into a numpy array. Also keep in mind that if you have a one-dimensional array, you also need to convert it to a two-dimensional one. For example, if you used only one column, then you need to do the following:

```
np.array(crsp.loc[:, 'mom2m'].reshape(-1, 1)
```

I do not know if it is necessary to apply grouping here, in my opinion it is not needed.
At the end, the library 'mglearn' is used to draw the result. The triangles show the center of each cluster.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import mglearn


def cluster(X, n_clusters):
    k_means = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
    y = k_means.fit_predict(X)
    return y, k_means

arr = np.array(crsp.loc[:, ['mom2m', 'mom48m']])
aaa = cluster(arr, 3)
aaa_result = aaa[1]


mglearn.discrete_scatter(arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1] , aaa[1].labels_, markers='o')
mglearn.discrete_scatter(aaa[1].cluster_centers_[:, 0],
                         aaa[1].cluster_centers_[:, 1], [0, 1, 2], markers='^', markeredgewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The reason I'm trying to group by the dates is because I want to use the mom2m~mom48m factors cross-sectionally=>perform k-means clustering=> make long-short portfolios based on the clusters.

Comment: @gejyn14 what do you want to see in the crsp['cluster_id'] column show? I managed to get the predicted labels of each row. They look like this:[0, 1, 0, 1]. Is that what you need?